# 17028 Invalid app info in play_integrity_token D/FirebaseAuth( 8903): Invoking original failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am developing a Flutter app and aiming to incorporate phone authentication via Firebase. I have completed all necessary Firebase integration steps, including the addition of SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints to the Firebase project. Following this, I updated the google-services.json file in the android/app directory and activated Play Integrity. Despite these efforts, I am encountering an error when attempting to send OTPs:

Error sending OTP: [Error: [auth/app-not-authorized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token ]]

This error message suggests a problem with the app's authorization for Firebase Authentication, potentially due to incorrect package name or SHA certificate fingerprints configuration in the Firebase Console, or an issue related to the Play Integrity setup.

Review Firebase Authentication Settings
In the Firebase Console, under the Authentication section, ensure that the phone authentication method is enabled and correctly configured Clean Build
After making changes, it's a good practice to perform a clean build of your app. You can do this by running flutter clean and then flutter build apk (for Android) or flutter build ios (for iOS).
If after following these steps, you're still facing the issue, it might be helpful to consult the Firebase and Flutter documentation for any updates on integrating Firebase Authentication with Flutter, or to reach out to Firebase support for more specific assistance